# Как запретить передачу с яндекс-карт?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Сделал, чтобы карта яндекса загружалась только при щелчке на клавишу, чтобы страница загружалась быстрее.  И вроде ДОМ яндекс-картами не нагружен, все чисто, при загрузке страницы слева надпись передача данных с api-яндекс-карты. 
Где проходит эта передача?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

no=0;
$('#showmaps').toggle(function(){
$('#map').slideDown(1000);
$(this).text('Скрыть карту');

if (no==0)
{
   ymaps.ready(init);
   setTimeout(function(){myMap.container.fitToViewport(); }, 1500);

//  
   no++;
}

}, function(){
$('#map').slideUp(1000);
$(this).text('Показать карту');
})

var myMap,
    myPlacemark;

function init(){     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
        center: [<? echo $data[1].' , '.$data[0]?>],
        zoom: 15,
    });
myMap.controls.add('smallZoomControl',{left:5, top:5});
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([<? echo $data[1].' , '.$data[0]?>], { 
        content: 'Елабуга!', 
        balloonContent: 'Сдается!' 
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
 }

</script>
```

Comment: Поднимаю вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта передача происходит при подключении скрипта yandex-maps-api (который тут: `http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full`).

Этот скрипт при загрузке страницы подгружает код с `http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0.25/release/combine.xml?modules=...`, а там его более 300kB. Этим объясняется задержка при загрузке страницы. Если её запретить, карты работать не будут.

Выйти из положения можно асинхронным подключением скрипта api - ресурсы будут подгружаться только при первом нажатии на кнопку. Сделать это можно, например, с помощью jQuery метода [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
// Возвращаем кэширование чтобы не добавлялись всякие параметры к URL скрипта
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});

var no = 0;

$('#showmaps').toggle(function(){
    // Показываем карту
    $('#map').slideDown(1000);
    $(this).text('Скрыть карту');

    if (no==0)
    {
        var myMap, myPlacemark;

        // Загружаем скрипт API. callback выполнится после его загрузки и выполнения
        $.getScript('http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&amp;lang=ru-RU', function(){

            // К этому моменту скрипт api уже загрузился и выполнился
            ymaps.ready(function(){

                // Показать карту
                myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
                    center: [55.761255,52.010905],
                    zoom: 15,
                });

                // и т.д.
                myMap.controls.add('smallZoomControl',{left:5, top:5});

                myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.761255,52.010905], { 
                    content: 'Елабуга!', 
                    balloonContent: 'Сдается!' 
                });

                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

                no++;

            });

            setTimeout(function(){
                myMap.container.fitToViewport();
            }, 1500);
        });
    }

    return false;
}, function(){
    // Прячем карту
    $('#map').slideUp(1000);
    $(this).text('Показать карту');
    return false;
});
```

Получается так: [http://jsfiddle.net/nXS2A/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nXS2A/show/light/)